# Unable to play video in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, video-streaming, html5-video

I tried to play video, which have it name and path stored in database. File do exist in specific folder and said folder is in the  scope of this project in this context

The result show video player but have no video play

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult DownloadVideo(String url, String filename)
        {
            ELSEntities db = new ELSEntities();
            string path = Server.MapPath(url);
            string fullpath = url+"/"+filename;
            ViewBag.vid = fullpath;
            return View();
        }
```

`url` and `filename` parameters example:

`url`: *~/App_Data/Video*

`filename`: *ETRG.mp4*

**View**

```
<h2>DownloadVideo</h2>
@ViewBag.vid
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="video-frame">
        <video width="630" height="420" controls="controls">
            <source src="@Url.Content(ViewBag.vid)" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have tried to use `FileResult`, video play successfully but user can not control that video in anyway

```
public FileResult DownloadVideo(String url, String filename)
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath(url);
            string fullpath = Path.Combine(path, filename);
            return File(fullpath, "video/mp4");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the storage folder `~/App_Data/Video`, which are protected by the project, thus can not be access to

The folder containing files must be change, then be included in the project